# SWT on OS X: how to make trees and tables striped

Tags: java, macos, swt

I want to avoid having to override each label provider. Is there a simpler approach to make trees and tables for OS X striped (altering background color - white, light-blue)?

Comment: http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.ui.tests/Eclipse-JFace-Tests/org/eclipse/jface/tests/labelProviders/DecoratingStyledCellLabelProviderTest.java.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want the alternating white/light-blue backgrounds that Mac OS typically provides?  (Like what's in iTunes, for example?)

Just call `setLinesVisible(true)` on your `Table`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [JFace Snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet041TableViewerAlternatingColors.java?view=markup)...